# Simple free program to add audio to video?

Tags: video, audio

I am looking for a small free tool that will allow me to add some audio to my video. Windows movie maker doesn't seem to work well from some reason.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Are you just trying to join an audio track to video?  If so, FFMPEG will work well for you.  If you don't already know what editing you need to do, you'll need a more robust video editing solution.

Comment: What about Windows Movie Maker doesn't work well? As far as I know it should allow you to add existing audio tracks to existing video, which seems to meet your criteria.

Answer (score 5):

I just used Windows Live Movie Maker exactly for that. It could be that it differs from Windows Movie Maker (which was superseded, afaik) on this aspect. You should try it, if you can.

Answer (score 3):

The command-line tool ffmpeg can do this perfectly well.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i input.mp3 -c copy output.mp4
```

If the input video alread has an audio track that you want to replace, you have to use `-map` options like so (this will take all video streams from the first input, and all audio streams from the second input):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i input.mp3 -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy output.mp4
```

It's an amazing tool, and if you want to you can do almost any editing task with it (short of chroma key, and even that will probably be added at some point).

See [here](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) for how to get ffmpeg (in your case, scroll down to 'Windows Builds').

Answer (score 0):

You can try YouTube Video Editor, it's an online free video maker, which can help you insert audio to video. But there is only one restrain, you need to upload your video to YouTube first.

Answer (score 0):

For this I would actually recommend MKV-merge, it has a nice gui interface, and if you are sattisfied with using MKV as the container (it can take almost every codec out there), then you are set.

MKV-merge will do absolutely no re-encoding, and will simply put whatever streams that you want, one besides another. The output of it can be played by any video player that is worth talking about.

If you need to have different container, then you should go with avlib or ffmpeg (whichever one you prefer).